# Why does there exists a random variable $x^n(t,\omega')$ such that $x_{k_r}^n$ converges to it

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Given a  sequence of stochastic process $\xi_n(t)$ defined for $t \in [t_0,T]$ on ($\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}$) such that its stochastically continuous. Now consider a dense set $t_1,t_2, \cdots,$ in $[t_0,T]$ and assume the existence of a sequence of random variables(they exist due to a deep result due to Skorokhod which I skip for reasons of brevity)on a new probability space ($\Omega',\mathcal{F}',\mathbb{P}'$)

$x_n=\{x_1^{(n)},x_2^{(n)},\dots,\} n=0,1,\dots$ such that $\left(x_1^{(n)},x_2^{(n)},\dots,\right)$ has the same joint distribution as $\left(\xi_n(t_1),\xi_n(t_2), \dots,\right)$ for all finite combinations of $t_i$ in the dense set  $t_1,t_2, \cdots,$ of $[t_0,T]$

Clearly the stochastic continuity of $\xi_n(t)$ implies that as $t_{k_r} \to t$ we have that $\xi_n(t_{k_r}) \to \xi_n(t)$ in probability

$\textbf{"Note that in the following $x^{(n)}_I(\omega')$ is a random variable on the space $(\Omega',\mathcal{F}',\mathbb{P}')$ AND NOT THE VALUE taken by the random variable at $\omega'$"}$

Now This is equivalent to 
$$\lim_{r \to \infty} E\left[\ \frac{\vert\xi_n(t_{k_r})-\xi_n(t)\vert}{1+\vert\xi_n(t_{k_r})-\xi_n(t)\vert}\right]=0$$. If $t=t_k$ for some $k$ in the sequence $t_1,t_2,\cdots,$ then since $\left(\xi_n(t_{k_r}),\xi_n(t)\right)$ has the same joint distribution as $\left(x_{k_r}^n(\omega'),x_k^n(\omega')\right)$, we have that 
$$\lim_{r \to \infty} E\left[\ \frac{\vert x_{k_r}^n(\omega')-x_k^n(\omega')\vert}{1+\vert x_{k_r}^n(\omega')-x_k^n(\omega')\vert}\right]=0$$ which is equivalent to saying that 
$x_{k_r}^n \to x_k^n(\omega')$ in probability.

What I CANT SHOW is that of for $t \neq t_k$ why does there exists some  random variable say $x^n(t,\omega')$ such that $x_{k_r}^n$ converges to it whenever $t_{k_r} \to  t$?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's covered by  the bits of the Skorokhod construction that you skipped?

Comment: @kimchilover . I read it all in excruciating detail .  I just didn’t write it down . I think it’s some basic probability argument which is escaping me . There are many gaps in the exposition which I couldn’t unfortunately fulfill in this case

Comment: Can't help you, then.  Usually a Skorokhod representation is set up to make the step that's puzzling you a triviality.  Look for an alternative exposition; maybe it will be clearer.

Comment: @kimchilover The problem is the Skorokhod representation gives me a countable sequence of $x_n$ but i somehow want to extend it to an uncoutable index set($\mathbb{R}_+$) of rvs

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, so I'm not sure if that's right, but I think you can make the following argument: since $\xi_n(t_{k_r})$ are converging in probability, they form a cauchy sequence; but then since the finite joint distributions are identical, this implies that $x^n_{k_r}$ are a cauchy sequence as well, and so by completeness they will converge to a random variables. Then I think that with the same type of argument you can show that the limit does not depend on the sequence $t_{k_r}$ chosen to approximate $t$.

Comment: @Lucio Cauchy sequence with respect to which metric ? It’s a Cauchy sequence if we can write the distance between the two points as a probability $\mathbb{P}(\vertx_{k_r}-x_{k_m}\vert > \epsilon)$. Why can we do that ?

Comment: I'm sure that convergence in  probability is induced by a metric and that in that way you obtain a complete metric space, but I don't remember exactly how it is formulated. If I should guess, I would say that given two random variables on the same probability space you can consider $d(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}[\vert X-Y\vert/(1+\vert X-Y\vert)]$, but it could also be  $d(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}[\inf(\vert X-Y\vert,1)]$